# Find the top edge of a distribution of points with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns 'a' , 'b'  and N rows.
I plot those points in a chart 'b' vs 'a' and I get a distribution of points as in figure (note that I do not have a mathematical expression that describe this distribution curve).[image]
I would like to find all the points that are on the top edge of the distribution I get (i.e. the points that describes the curve profile).
For a given value of a, it corresponds to several values of b , so I groupby 'a' and I got the max value of 'b' for each group.
This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import numpy as np

#initializzation
path = 'my_folder'
tracks = os.listdir(path)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18.5, 9.9))

#functions
def read_track(i):
    track_path = '/'.join([path,tracks[i]])
    df = pd.read_csv(track_path, delimiter=';')
    df = remove_negative(df)
    return df

#I just want positive value for b
def remove_negative(df):
    df.loc[df['b']<=0, 'b'] = 0
    return df

def find_profile(df, min, max):
    max_b = df.groupby(['a'])['b'].max()
    max_b = max_b[min:max].reset_index()   
    return max_b.loc[max_b['b'] > 0]

#code execution with the first sample (0)

df = read_track(0)
profile = find_profile(df, 0, 10)
```

Unfortunatly there are some near 'a' points that have very different values in 'b' so the result is that I can't get the correct profile of my distribution.
Here an image of the result I get: [image: ana]
I thought to group again each 'a' point with its 5 (or more) closest neighbors and find the max 'b' ('b_max') within this group, then accept just the point with coordinates ('a', 'b_max') .
But I don't like so much this solution because I would downsample my distribution and also I could lost some important points.
Is there any other way to solve my problem ?

Thanks in advice

Andrea

Comment: I think your approach to group nearest neighbours sounds like a good idea, but perhaps try it with the 1 or 2 nearest and see what happens. Do you have some sample data so we can test an approach?